# Algorithm W using recursion schemes

Tags: haskell, recursion, type-inference, hindley-milner, recursion-schemes

I wanted to be able to formulate the hindley-milner type inference algorithm using fix-point data types and recursion schemes. 
Disregarding all detail apart from the actual recursion parts:

```
w env term = case term of 
    Lam n e -> lam (w (modify1 env) e)
    App a b -> app (w (modify2 env) a) (w (modify3 env) b)
    ...
```

The algorithm builds an environment data structure `env` as it recursively traverses the tree until it reaches the leafs. Then it uses this information as it builds up the result again.

Without the `env` part, this could be easily implemented with `cata`.
Can this (with `env`) be done in general using recursion schemes?

Comment: Yes just make the target of the cata a function `Env -> a`

Comment: Yes, but you'll probably need to use `cata` with a higher-order carrier type, computing an action that can modify the environment and possibly fail.

Comment: Got it. Genius. Thanks

Comment: @user47376 something about it feels a bit magical, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

> Without the env part, this could be easily implemented with cata. Can this (with env) be done in general using recursion schemes?

What you're looking for is a [chronomorphism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:chrono). This allows you to do recursion using *both* results from the future and the past. It's not quite as user-friendly as it sounds, but it is the canonical way of doing things using recursion schemes.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes just make the target of the `cata` a function `Env -> a`

– luqui

> Yes, but you'll probably need to use `cata` with a higher-order carrier type, computing an action that can modify the environment and possibly fail.

– pigworker

Comment: *Now* write algorithm W as a tail-recursive traversal using the *same* data structure as both the zipper and the environment of unification variables. You'll be glad you did.